# ios 17 interactive widget api call in background

Tags: background, widget, xcode8, ios17

An API request is being made through the Interactive Widget in iOS 17.0. The desired situation is to request an API through the widget's Intent and receive a response from the server. (Because it is opened from Intent, the app does not open.) But a problem occurred here.

When both the main app and the widget are built, the above request works well. However, even if the build is stopped, the request is made normally if the app is in the foreground state.

However, when the app is in the background, API calls are not made through Intent. How can I solve this?

Desired situation:

API call request through App Intent under any network condition when the app is turned off (may not be reflected separately in the widget)

Problem Situation:

1. An API call through Celluar Data fails when the app is turned off

What's currently working properly:

1. Successful API call through Wi-Fi when the app is turned off

2. An API call is successful under any network conditions when the app is turned on!